# Combining Swipe menu and swipe screen

Tags: mobile, menu, swipe, multiple-screens

Is there a good way to combine a swipe menu with the ability to swipe multiple screen? Or is the idea generally bad?
The idea is to create a swipe menu to select from multiple screens(let's say 6) and as my app has 3 main screen, I would like to create a way to easily access those 3 screens without going to the menu.( just a swipe rather than a swipe and a tap).

Comment: Can we get more detail here? Low information in the question means low quality in the answers. If you can explain your specific situation we can cater the response to help that more specifically.

Comment: Would the swipe menu be swipe in one direction (i.e. from L to R) and then swipe between views be the other direction (R to L)?

Comment: Menu will come from a left to right swipe. Are you suggesting a right to left swipe for screen changes (as in round robin style - circular screen change)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of windows phone apps have a menu that slides up from the bottom like this:

[image]

while also supporting screen swiping (used to be known as "metro style"), where the user gets a visual hint that there is something to the right

[image]

[A nice description of this design pattern is here.](http://windowsphonepatterns.net/uap_pattern/application-menu)